# Strange ruby to_yaml behavior

Tags: ruby, yaml

I got this weird problem with difference in behavior of `to_yaml`. For:

```
"0111".to_yaml
```

it returns:

```
"--- \"0111\"\n"
```

At the same time this:

```
"0128".to_yaml
```

returns:

```
"--- 0128\n"
```

As you can see the first output have `""` but the second doesn't.

Any idea?

Environment: MRI Ruby 1.9.2 and JRuby 1.6.5 (1.9 mode).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe Eugene is right about the reason for these issue - seems like parser treats strings containing valid octal numbers differently.

If you don't like it you can switch to a different YAML parser. According to [docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/yaml/rdoc/YAML.html) there are two parsers available: `Syck` and `Psych`. The former is old and unmaintained and the latter is its replacement.

`Psych` is used in latest versions of Rails and is default YAML engine in 1.9.3. But you can easily use it in 1.9.2 and see the difference:

```
require 'yaml'

p YAML::ENGINE.yamler      # => "syck"
# or explicitly set YAML::ENGINE.yamler = "syck" in 1.9.3
p '01'.to_yaml             # => "--- \"01\"\n"
p '08'.to_yaml             # => "--- 08\n"
p YAML.load('01'.to_yaml)  # => "01"
p YAML.load('08'.to_yaml)  # => "08"

p YAML::ENGINE.yamler = "psych"
p '01'.to_yaml             # => "--- '01'\n"
p '08'.to_yaml             # => "--- '08'\n"
p YAML.load('01'.to_yaml)  # => "01"
p YAML.load('08'.to_yaml)  # => "08"
```

As you can see there is no need to worry about different representation of strings in `Syck` as long as you're using the same engine to decode data (in both cases it returns original strings).

If for some reason you need unified representation for strings in YAML you can switch to `Psych` (it's more consistent at least in this case), but be careful as you might get in troubles trying to load with `Psych` data that was previously dumped with `Syck`.

Comment: Didn't know the YAML parser was changed in 1.9.3, good to know.  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: I'm running `ruby 1.9.3p194` on OS X (installed via RVM) and even though `YAML::ENGINE.yamler` reports `"psych"` I _still_ get the above behavior with `'08'` and `'09'`.

Comment: So do I. In 1.9.3 with `psych` I get the same behavior as with `syck` in 1.9.2. I guess the reason is that in 1.9.2 I have `psych` version `1.0.0` and in 1.9.3 it's `1.3.2`. Most likely they changed the behavior in the latest versions.

Answer (score 0):

I can duplicate this as well.  I'm not sure what is doing it, but my first guess is that it has do with the "numbers" in the string actually being octal numbers.  Or more accurately, the first being octal, and the second not.  If you remove the 0, you get the behavior from the first on both of them.  Perhaps somebody else could elaborate on this theory.

```
1.9.2p290 :002 > "0111".to_yaml
  => "--- \"0111\"\n" 
1.9.2p290 :003 > "0128".to_yaml
  => "--- 0128\n" 
1.9.2p290 :004 > "\0111".to_yaml
  => "--- \"\\t1\"\n" 
1.9.2p290 :005 > "\0128".to_yaml
  => "--- \"\\n\\\n8\"\n" 
1.9.2p290 :006 > string = "0111"
  => "0111" 
1.9.2p290 :007 > string.class
 => String 
1.9.2p290 :008 > string.to_yaml
 => "--- \"0111\"\n" 
1.9.2p290 :009 > string = "111"
 => "111" 
1.9.2p290 :010 > string.to_yaml
 => "--- \"111\"\n" 
1.9.2p290 :011 > string = "128"
 => "128" 
1.9.2p290 :012 > string.to_yaml
 => "--- \"128\"\n"
```

Comment: I just feel this behavior is very strange. I test on other yaml implementation like js-yaml. Seems they handle this in the correct way...